# How do I reflect changes in user data of some external source (eg: Facebook, LinkedIn etc) if I'm using their API?

Tags: android, api, linkedin-api, social-networking, real-time-updates

So I'm using LinkedIn's API as a means of logging in for the user on my Android app, but I think this question could be generalized for the use of any social network's API and isn't really specific to Android either. Anyways...

When I call LinkedIn's API, I get some user data after they login -- in particular, their name, email, skills, profile description etc. I know that some of this data might change when the user edits his profile on LinkedIn's website (for example, adds a new skill).

Now, I want these changes to reflect on my app as soon as possible. All I can think of to do this is to simply call the API every time the user returns to the app, get the data and replace it with whatever I stored from the last call.

But this seems problematic because for many users it's probable that they rarely make any changes to their profile on LinkedIn... so it seems like a huge waste of time making a call every time the user opens the application. But if I make the call at larger intervals -- say every few days -- then I'd risk not reflecting any changes some people might make.

So I was wondering if there was any alternate solution to having to make all these calls. Do such API's like those of Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and other social networks have a way to be notified of changes (or are there other libraries out there with this functionality)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook does have something along the lines of what you are looking for: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/app/subscriptions/

You can opt to subscribe to updates to a User object, and they'll call an endpoint that you give them whenever something changes.

As far as I can tell, LinkedIn doesn't offer similar functionality. However, I wouldn't stress too much about making this call when you open the app. It's only one call retrieving a small amount of data. Of course, you'd want to make sure that the app doesn't fail to load if the call fails - you'd just want that to mean that the information isn't updated.

Is the app standalone, or do you have a server component? Another option would be to have the server making this call on behalf of the user.

Comment: Right now I have no server component, but if I did, how would it change - I would still have to make calls to my server every time I enter the app right? Or is there some way I can have the server send the app the data whenever it finds changes made on the LinkedIn site, and implement some sort of background service on the app locally that listens for the server sending it data? But then again, that seems much more expensive in terms of resources than just making a call to LinkedIn's API every time the app is used. I'm just trying to gauge how developers tackle this problem usually really.

Comment: Like you say, it would probably be a lot more expensive to run a background service that's listening for updates. I don't think it'll be too expensive to just make a call to LinkedIn's API when you load the app. I'd just recommend making that call in a thread other than the UI thread, and like I said before, cope with its failure gracefully.